# models don't register in django admin

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin, admin

I have 2 models which is Listing and Realtor

```
class Listing(models.Model):
  #somethings

class Realtor(models.Model):
  #somethings
```

and in admin.py in listing package:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Listing

admin.site.register(Listing)
```

and admin.py in realtors package:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Realtor

admin.site.register(Realtor)
```

and the setting of project is:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'pages.apps.PagesConfig',
'listings.apps.ListingsConfig',
'realtors.apps.RealtorsConfig',
```

]

but in admin panel there aren't registeredand there is no error while runing server

Answer (score 1):

I solved it
I must run **makemigrations and migrate**!

> but I don't know the reason!!
> please comment if you know the reason

Answer (score 0):

and admin.py in realtors package:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Listing

admin.site.register(Realtor)
```

Here you didn't import `Realtor`

It should be such:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Realtor

admin.site.register(Realtor)
```

Comment: yes that's mu mistake while typing but it doesn't work yet

Comment: @amirhossein isn't any error showing in terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Adblock can hide registered models in the admin panel. Try of it

Comment: It seems that this is not an answer to the question, and this is more of just a comment that you can add to the question in order not to confuse the others.